# window.body.scrollHeight does not change when decreasing height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to create a way to detect when the body resizes and then I grab the new height and send it through a postmessage. The not correctly functioning part is when I downsize the body ( when I removed(hide) some elements so the body shrunk). This does not get detected as the window.body.scrollHeight simply holds the last value. 
Here is my code and I would appreciate any suggestions:

```
  sendMessage();
  checkDocumentHeight(sendMessage);
  function sendMessage(){
    var heightWidth = document.body.scrollHeight+ " " +document.body.scrollWidth;
    parent.postMessage(heightWidth, "*");
  }
  function checkDocumentHeight(callback){
      var lastHeight = document.body.scrollHeight, newHeight, timer;
      (function run(){
          newHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
          if( lastHeight != newHeight )
              callback();
          lastHeight = newHeight;
          timer = setTimeout(run, 1000);
      })();
  }
```

Comment: window.resize not doing it for you?

Comment: can you create a simple example to show us in fiddle?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

scrollHeight with not change, you want to use the innerHeight. scrollHeight is basically the same as document height. It's the height of the scrollbar.

```
window.innerHeight
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gUUYc/4/

Comment: That actually returns undefined on my side.

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? It shouldn't return undefined at all